# Why my php is not up to date

Tags: php, yum, update

I use Yum on Fedora 11 to update my computer.

On my box, I have

```
[luc@zappa locale]$ php --version
PHP 5.2.9 (cli) (built: Apr 15 2009 09:30:33) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

[But according to this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Php), my version is not supported.

I guess that I could un-install and re-install it with yum

```
yum remove php
yum install php
```

There is another way to ugrade my php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP 5.2.9 is the version of PHP that comes with Fedora 11. You can't yum install a newer version (at least not when using the default Fedora repositories). You could install from source but I wouldn't recommend doing that unless you know what you're doing. Is there something particular about it being unsupported that is a problem? Because, in theory, the Fedora maintainers are keeping 5.2.9 patched for, what, like another year.

Comment: Also, technically speaking, Fedora 11 comes with PHP 5.2.9-2, so you can tell the maintainers have done at least something with it.

Answer (score 1):

Any update system that uses anything other than source code is likely to be at least a little behind the latest version. It may therefore be that the version of PHP you have is the latest available from the Yum repositories you are using.